# CSVHelper How to not hardcode indexes

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have the following code:

```
public static void WriteRecords(string fileSpecification, string[] headerRow, Type classMapType, int[] indexes, IEnumerable<object> records)
{
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileSpecification))
    using (CsvWriter csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, noHeaderConfiguration))
    {
        csvWriter.Context.RegisterClassMap(classMapType); // How do I pass in the indexes without hardcoding
        WriteHeader(headerRow, csvWriter);
        csvWriter.NextRecord();
        csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);
    }
}
// Edit One of the maps, does not mean only one I am calling.

public sealed class TimeZone_StartDate_Value_isGood_Description_FormatModelMap : ClassMap<TimeZone_StartDate_Value_isGood_Description_FormatModel>
    {


        public TimeZone_StartDate_Value_isGood_Description_FormatModelMap(int[] indexes)
{
            
            Map(m => m.TimeZone).Index(indexes[0]);
            Map(m => m.StartDate).Index(indexes[1]);
            Map(m => m.Value).Index(indexes[2]);
            Map(m => m.IsGoodString).Index(indexes[3]);
            Map(m => m.Description).Index(indexes[4]);

        }
}
// Edit 2 WriteHeader Method, asked to be included. Write header row for csv

private static void WriteHeader(string[] headerRow, CsvWriter csvWriter)
{
            for (int i = 0; i < headerRow.Length; i++)
            {
                csvWriter.WriteField(headerRow[i]);
            }
}
```

I want to pass in int[] indexes to a map. The map is determined by parameter Type classMapType. The class map( not included here) has a constructor that takes in int[]. How does one achieve this?

I have tried Activator.CreateInstance() but that returns a object.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:
I included one of the class maps, does not mean it is the only one called.

I tried to use .GetType() but returns error because there is no ctor with zero parameters. Tried to find another method but could not.

Comment: I think we need more info/code to help you here. `WriteHeader`, the definition of your class map, what does `indexes` represent, what are you expecting for output?

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope this helps. Please let me know if this is not enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
csvWriter.Context.RegisterClassMap(new MyClassMap(indexes));
```

Comment: Thanks! Set a path for me on how to proceed with this project.